# Can we update a mapping in parent contract from child contract?

Tags: solidity, mapping

I had passed the value(key value pair) to a mapping in parent contract from child contract for updating and the program executes without any error. But when I enter key in the mapping from parent contract it shows like nothing stored in the mapping. Can someone give me any solution?

```
pragma solidity >0.4.0;
contract admin{
struct patient{
string name;
uint age;
}

mapping(uint=>patient) public pdb;

function reg(uint id,string memory pname, uint p_age) public {
pdb[id].name=pname;
pdb[id].age=p_age;
}

}

contract user is admin{
function vacc_reg(uint id,string memory name, uint a) public{
   reg(id,name,a);
}
}
```

Comment: Hey RSK, welcome to StackExchange. For us to be able to help you out, you may need to share a code snippet that reproduces the error.

Comment: attached the code :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing being a "parent contract" with the idea of inheritance. [This answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/64736/inheritence-in-solidity) does a really good job of differentiating between the two with code samples.